# is this mold where I have taken the wallpaper off?

Tags: walls, mold

I have started removing the wallpaper in my house and I've noticed this black stuff where the plaster has come off. I'm not sure what it is. I have tried looking at images of mold but not sure. It feels rough and dry. Could someone identify what it is?[image]

Comment: Don't think so, looks more that what is under the wall paper is made of something black colour(or painted).

Comment: Looks kike a masonry product that was covered with a finish coat of plaster.

Comment: I agree with d.George it looks like a dark colored base coat was used.

Answer (score 1):

Where in the world are you?
In the UK in an old Victorian build that would be what they used to 'plaster' the walls with. idk what the heck it's made of (it looks like dried mud;) but by now it will be only slightly more structurally stable than a pile of dry sand.*

The white layer you can see around it is the plaster skim itself. You've knocked the skim off to expose this 'mud' base layer. It needs re-skimming, but you will have to stabilise the base layer first & ensure its adherence to the wall behind, otherwise the weight of fresh wet plaster is likely to just pull it all off.

Thinned-down PVA glue will do it, but you will need patience & time. Initially paint over the surface & allow it to soak in & dry. Repeat this a couple of times - the surface will get more water-proof each time so you'll know when that won't help any further.
If the layer is particularly deep, which you will only find out by knocking some of it out, then you may need to also inject deeper into it using PVA & a printer-ink or vape syringe & blunt needle.

If it falls off in chunks, you may end up having to have the entire wall stripped & re-plastered, so use your skill & judgement, & don't rush it.

* Basically, on these old houses, the 'mud' is held up by the plaster skim (& often 8 layers of gloss paint) & that is held up in turn by the wallpaper - more good luck than anything else that it hasn't all fallen off yet. If you handle it wrong, it will need re-doing from scratch, knock it all off right back to the brickwork.
This is a job that will coat the entire house in a pervasive layer of fine black dust for a month - avoid at all costs.